# Listview setOnItemClickListener in kotlin

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, onclicklistener

So im trying to use setOnItemClickListener to click in a list view and with that change to another layout bringing de info that i clicked, but first i cant even change of layout. Im trying to go from Clube to clube_detalhado but nothing is happening,not even a toast.

```
class Clube : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clubes, container, false) as View

    val listView : ListView = view.findViewById(R.id.clubes_list)


    var names: ArrayList<NewsObject> = arrayListOf(
            NewsObject(R.drawable.sportingim, "Sporting","15 JOGOS 367 GOLOS"),
            NewsObject(R.drawable.manunited, "Manchester United","15 JOGOS 367 GOLOS"),
            NewsObject(R.drawable.realim, "Real Madrid","15 JOGOS 367 GOLOS"),
            NewsObject(R.drawable.juv, "Juventus","15 JOGOS 367 GOLOS"),
            NewsObject(R.drawable.selecao, "Seleção Nacional","15 JOGOS 367 GOLOS")
    )

    listView.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(requireContext(),names)


    listView.setOnItemClickListener {_,_, position, _ ->

        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"burro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        //val imagemnova: String = names[position].img.toString()
        //val titulonovo: String = names[position].title
        //val descrinova: String = names[position].desc
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), Clube_detalhado::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


    return view

}
```

This is my clube_detalhado

```
class Clube_detalhado : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_clube_detalhado)
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to debug your code?

Comment: yes i tried and nothing happened